# Multiple templates declared in one .vue file

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component inside a .vue file that can benefit from reusing a chunk of code. I know I can move that code to a separate .vue file and import it as a new component. However, this component would not be used anywhere else and I'd like to avoid cluttering the directory. Is it possible to declare this component's template inside the parent without using the in-code `template:"<div>.....</div>"` stuff?

This is the idea:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    ...some html here...
    <div v-for="item in items">
      {{item.name}}: 
      <div v-if="item.available">YES!</div>
      <div v-else>NO :(</div>     
    </div>    

    ...some other components and data here...

    <div v-for="item in items">
      {{item.name}}: 
      <div v-if="item.available">YES!</div>
      <div v-else>NO :(</div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</template>
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    ...some html here...
    <div v-for="item in items">
      <itemizer inline-template v-model="item">
        {{value.name}}: 
        <div v-if="value.available">YES!</div>
        <div v-else>NO :(</div>
      </itemizer>
    </div>    

    ...some other components and data here...

    <div v-for="item in items">
      <itemizer v-model="item"/>
    </div>    
  </div>
</template>
```

However, from what I understand this is not possible.

Comment: BTW, I don't think you can have a v-model on a inline-template element.

Comment: i'd be fine with :param="....."

Comment: I think you actually need to pass in "item" as a prop.  I'll make an example below.

Comment: yes, i know, i was making this example just for speed, but that's not the point. my question is how to reuse the inline-template'd component elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this pattern does not appear to be supported by the creator of Vue:

> I personally feel the syntax is less maintainable than [Single File Components]
>
> Note that we want to keep the SFC syntax as consistent possible, because it involves a big ecosystem of tools that need to support any new features added (e.g. Vetur would need to do something very different for handling SFCs with multiple scripts/templates). The proposed syntax, IMO, does not justify adding the new syntax.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/7264#issuecomment-352452213

That's too bad, as even beyond flexibility and developer choice, there is a good argument for inlining small functions that are not used by other components in order to reduce complexity. It's a common pattern in React and does not inhibit Single File Components when they're needed. In fact it allows gradual migration as inline components grow.

---

Here's one of the only resources currently that offers some potential workarounds:
https://codewithhugo.com/writing-multiple-vue-components-in-a-single-file/

I've tried them all and am not satisfied with any of them at this time. At best you can set `runtimerCompiler: true` and use template strings, but it'll add 10KB to your bundle and you'll likely miss out on full syntax highlighting available in the `<template>` element.  Maybe you can hack [Teleport](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/teleport.html#using-with-vue-components), but I have not made a dedicated attempt.

Comment: I wish that PR didn't ask for multiple template *and* script sections :/. I can't a use for multiple script sections. Script already have a reuse mechanism in SFC - variables ... where as this is not the case for template. Maybe Evan like more if just template.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this should work.  Just register your Vue inline-template like this in the  section of your parent .vue file:

```html
<template>

    <div v-for="item in items">
        <test-template :item="item">
            <h1>{{item.text}}</h1>
        </test-template>
    </div>

</template>


<script>
    Vue.component('test-template', {
        template:'#hello-world-template',
        props: {
            item: Object
        }
    });

    export default {...}
</script>
```

In your parent HTML file, put this:

```html
<script type="text/x-template" id="hello-world-template">
    <p>Hello hello hello</p>
</script>
```

Comment: yes, but when i try to use `<test-template/>` elsewhere in the code, it says template or render function not defined. and defining inline template every time is pointless since the whole idea is to reuse the same code

Comment: Hi @andrei - actually one of the strengths of the inline template is you can use the same JS with different HTML.  If you want to reuse the HTML, then you won't want an inline-template.

Comment: I'd like to reuse both, HTML and JS. is that possible in a single .vue file?

Comment: Yeah, I think you can use the `template` property.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: yes, but that means I have to create the entire template in JS in quotes. and it gets cumbersome since my "sub"component is almost 30 lines with various v-if's, v-on's and v-bind's

Comment: ah, i see.  I know of yet another alternative.  I'll update again :)

Comment: this is called an "x-template"

Comment: ah, ok, that basically means i'm declaring the sub-component in the grandparent .vue file?

Comment: Yeah, it's proving a bit screwy for me when I try using a variable in the x-template, but it is printing out the object in the DOM for me so I think it might work.  However, I think the easiest thing to do (and the way this is meant to work) would be to make another child .vue component, and you could just register it locally rather than globally if you like.

Comment: Notice the docs say using the x-template "can be useful for demos with large templates or in extremely small applications, but should otherwise be avoided, because they separate templates from the rest of the component definition." - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#X-Templates

Comment: Alternatively, you could make do with using single-quotes for the template property on the component object.  It's a little annoying, but do you have that many single quotes in your 30 lines of HTML? If so, can you escape them? (just to be clear, I think another child .vue file is your best bet here).

Comment: yes, i could do that, I have a few single quotes, and i could escape them, but for now i just duplicated the HTML, since I'm using it only in 2 places. I guess if there's no clean or easy way to do this, i'll just stick to my solution.

Comment: I also read about the x-templates before, but i couldn't figure out a good way to use them precisely because it doesn't work well in the same .vue file

Answer (score 2):

With vue3 there are multiple options:

1. with vue-jsx you can just declare a component in your script setup section and use that

```
const Named = defineComponent(() => {
  const count = ref(0)
  const inc = () => count.value++

  return () => (
    <button class="named" onClick={inc}>
      named {count.value}
    </button>
  )
})
```

2. There is another option described by Michael Thiessen [here](https://michaelnthiessen.com/multiple-components-in-one-file/)
3. Also you can have multiple render function components in one file:
   https://staging.vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not supported in Vue core yet, there is a way to use this through [vue macros](https://vue-macros.sxzz.moe/macros/) project. See discussion [here](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/6863)